# Stancl/Tenancy - How do i automatically run the migrations when a new tenant is created?

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

When i create a new tenant the migrations for the new tenant doesnt run and I was wondering how I would automatically run the migrations for the newly created tenant after it is created. Is there an artisan command that has to be run in the background for it to work? Here is my controllers code so far when a request comes  through to create a tenant.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'company' => 'required',
            'domain' => 'required|unique:domains',
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|confirm'
        ]);
        $tenant_id = '-' . Str::slug($request->company, '-');
        $domain = $request->domain . '.' . 'saas.test';

        $tenant = Tenant::create([
            'id' => $tenant_id
        ]);


        $tenant->createDomain([
            'domain' => $domain
        ]);

        $tenant->run(function()
        {
            User::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
            ]);
        });

        tenancy()->initialize($tenant);

        return redirect($domain);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run artisan command in your controller method: `Artisan::call(‘tenants:migrate’);`

Comment: doesnt do anything.

Comment: i got it to work, i just did Artisan::call('tenants:migrate')

Comment: My bad. Next time I will be more focused on the answer